# OwnCloud Download speed really slow

Tags: performance, debian, owncloud

I'm using owncloud for the first time, I have two dedicated servers one with SSD drive which hosts the owncloud and a second server with a larger raid storage on SAS disks both servers have a **dedicated 100Mbps** line. I have mounted the disks from the storage server into my OwnCloud server and it indexes the few files I have without issues.

When I come to download those files to my home computer via the owncloud web interface (**on a 150Mbps lin**e) the max speed I can get is **160KB/s**

When I get the same file directly from the storage server it downloads at around **7.8MB/s** which is about what I would expect.

What is throttling the downloads via the OwnCloud web interface? From a Google search this seems to be a common issue with OwnCloud but doesn't have a solid answer. There seems to be no limiting built into OwnCloud according to the GitHub threads.